# How to copy table to my computer from network database , if I haven't right superuser? POSTGRES

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to copy a **Postgres** table in **CSV** format from a network database to my computer.
For example, here is its address

```bash
psql postgresql://login:password@192.168.00.00:5432/test_table
```

The problem is that I don't have superuser rights and I can't copy the table via pg_admin.

For example, if I make a request in pg_admin:

```sql
COPY test_table TO 'C:\tmp\test_table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I get an error:

> ERROR: must be superuser or a member of the pg_write_server_files role to COPY to a file
> HINT: Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
> SQL state: 42501

As I understand it, it is possible to copy the table - but through the command line, right? How to do it in my case? Thank

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `COPY` with a path, use `STDOUT`. Then, redirect the output to a local path:

```bash
psql -c "COPY test_table TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER" >> C:\tmp\test_table.csv
```

See the documentation for [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

---

In case you need this explanation: **stdout** stands for *standard output*, it means that the result of the command should be printed on your terminal. Using `>>` you *redirect* the output of the `psql` command to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I would just learn how to use the command line, but if you want to stick with pgAdmin4 you can right click on the table in the browser tree and then choose "Import/Export Data" and follow the dialog box.  Doing that is basically equivalent to using `\copy` from psql.